# Append data to an existing JSON array with SwiftyJSON

Tags: swift, swifty-json

I have an array of `SwiftyJSON`that I have declared and added data to it. 
The `JSON` data gets filtered with a logic in `cellForRowAt` closure.
I would want to append data to another existing `SwiftyJSON` variable.

```
var jsonObj: JSON = JSON() // With JSON DATA
var filteredJSON: JSON = JSON() // Data to be added after filtration

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //..... Used jsonObj data and created a value for 'obj'

    if obj.altitude.wrappedValue > 0 {
        var filtr = JSON(jsonObj[indexPath.row].object)
        filteredJSON.arrayObject?.append(filtr)
    }
    print("filteredJSON:", filteredJSON) // null
}
```

In the end `filteredJSON` always return null